# How can i directly covert the string into number in template literals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, django-templates

### How can i directly convert the string into number in template literals in javascript?

Actually i am working on django templating for loop.
My HTML is:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<button id="bt">Button</button>
```

My views.py is:

```
addpost = list(addPost.objects.filter(category='Technology').values())
context = json.dumps({"addDict":addpost})
return render(request, "blog/technology.html", {"addDict":context, "addpost":addpost})
```

My Javascript code:

```
<script>
 var data = JSON.parse("{{addDict|escapejs}}");
 data = data["addDict"];
 let showContent = document.querySelector(".container");
 var start = 5;
 var end = 8;
 function buttonClickHandler(){
 console.log(typeof end);
 let text = (`
<div class="container1">
{% for show in addpost|slice:"5:${end}" %}
{% ifequal show.category "Technology" %}
<div class="post">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com" alt="">
<div>
<span><b style="font-size:14px;">Tariq Ahmed </b><span style="font-size:12px;">in </span><b style="font-size:14px;">{{show.category}}</b></span>
</div>
<h6>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore rerum ipsam dolore error.</h6>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum natus optio facere accusamus soluta consequuntur---</p>
<p><a href="">Read more . </a><span>4 min read</span></p>
</div>
{% endifequal %}
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.last %}
</div>
<div class="container1">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
    `);
    showContent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);
}
bt.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler)
</script>
```

i have a problem in javacript code in this line
*{% for show in addpost|slice:"5:${end}" %}*
When i am using varaible in template-literals it returns string type, this creating a problem, but when i type manually any number it works fine. My question is how can i convert directly into number within literals?

if you do not get understand this method so please tell me other method, how can i show my some posts on html page, and if user click load more button 6 other posts are shown below through ajax or whatever and if user again click so on 6 posts increase every time click of user.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Running the code ```var a = 9;console.log(typeof a) // number; `hello${a}`;console.log(typeof a) // number;``` reveals that a does not change its type when it is interpolated in a string. The value of a will be coerced into a string, but that is because it is impossible to put a number type in a string type. That said, it looks like you may be mixing your javascript and python code together.

Comment: No bro! i already checked it, console.log(typeof  `${4}`) gives //string it means that ${} always return string type, but when i typecast like console.log(typeof  parseInt`${4}`) it gives //number but i can't apply this method within template-literals.

Comment: if you do not get understand this method so please tell me other method, how can i show my  some posts on html page  ,and  if user click load more button 6 other posts are shown below through ajax or whatever and user click so on 6  posts increase every time click of user..

Comment: Yeah bro! If you interpolate a number into a string, it's a string. It looks like you are trying to create a string of python code in a js file. I can't imagine how this is supposed to work.

Comment: so why it works when i manually enter 8 instead of end variable?

Comment: Similary ${8} not works but only 8 works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    var data = JSON.parse("{{addDict|escapejs}}");
    data = data["addDict"];
    let showContent = document.querySelector(".container");
    var start = 5;
    var end = 8;
    function buttonClickHandler(){
    console.log(typeof end);
    let text = (`
<div class="container1">
{% for show in addpost|slice:"5:${+end}" %}
{% ifequal show.category "Technology" %}
<div class="post">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com" alt="">
<div>
<span><b style="font-size:14px;">Tariq Ahmed </b><span style="font-size:12px;">in </span><b style="font-size:14px;">{{show.category}}</b></span>
</div>
<h6>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore rerum ipsam dolore error.</h6>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum natus optio facere accusamus soluta consequuntur---</p>
<p><a href="">Read more . </a><span>4 min read</span></p>
</div>
{% endifequal %}
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.last %}
</div>
<div class="container1">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
    `);
    showContent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);
}
bt.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler)
</script>
```

if end is string then you can put a "+" before that now it will be a number

Comment: No bro! i already checked it, console.log(typeof ${4}) gives //string it means that ${} always return string type, but when i typecast like console.log(typeof parseInt${4}) it gives //number but i can't apply this method within template-literals.

if you do not get understand this method so please tell me other method, how can i show my some posts on html page ,and if user click load more button 6 other posts are shown below through ajax or whatever and user click so on 6 posts increase every time click of user.

Answer (score 0):

We can use plus. For example:

```
var personAge = '24';
var personAge1 = (+personAge)
```

then if we see the new variable's type by typeof `personAge`1 ; which is `number`.